# Как вызвать значение нестатического поля в других классах?

Tags: c#, классы, циклы

Итак, дано первое обработчик (SaveBidAndOfferHandler)который при наступлении какого то внешнего события - изменение внешних отслеживаемых параметров, на основе этих параметров вычисляет переменную BegBid.

```js
namespace scalp
{
    public class SaveBidAndOfferHandler
    {
        private string symbol;
        private OrderBookContext orderBook;
        private Logger logger;
        private int currentIndex, maxIndex;
        private double BidPrice, BidVolume;
        public double BigBid;
        public SaveBidAndOfferHandler(string symbol,
            OrderBookContext orderBook,
            int maxIndex,
            Logger logger)
        {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.orderBook = orderBook;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.currentIndex = 0;
            this.maxIndex = maxIndex;

            this.orderBook.OnQuotesUpdate += new SymbolDataHasBeenUpdatedNotification(OnChange);
        }

        public void OnChange(string symbol)
        {
            if (this.symbol != symbol)
                return;

            if (this.currentIndex == this.maxIndex - 1)

            { this.currentIndex = 0; this.BigBid = 0; }


            CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            BidPrice = this.orderBook.GetBidPrice(this.symbol, this.currentIndex);
            BidVolume = this.orderBook.GetBidVolume(this.symbol, this.currentIndex);


            {
                if (BidVolume > 40)
                { BigBid = BidPrice; this.currentIndex = 0; }

                if (BidVolume < 41) this.currentIndex++;

            }

        }
        
    }
        }
```

Второй класс на основании событий входящих параметров и вычислений первого класса производит определенные действия (пока неважно какие).

```js
namespace scalp
{
    public class Open
    {
        private Strategy strategy;
        private OrderBookContext orderBook;
        private ObservableQueue<Signal> signalQueue;
        private TradingDataContext tradingData;
        private Logger logger;

        public Open(Strategy strategy,
            OrderBookContext orderBook,
            ObservableQueue<Signal> signalQueue,
            TradingDataContext tradingData,
            Logger logger) 
        {
            this.strategy = strategy;
            this.orderBook = orderBook;
            this.signalQueue = signalQueue;
            this.tradingData = tradingData;
            this.logger = logger;

            this.orderBook.OnQuotesUpdate += new SymbolDataHasBeenUpdatedNotification(OnChange);
        }

        private void OnChange(string symbol)
        {
            if (this.strategy.Symbol != symbol)
                return;

            if (StrategyPositionExists())
                return;

            if (UnfilledOrdersExists())
                return;

           

            Order lastOrder = GetLastFilledOrder();

            TradeAction action = GetAction(lastOrder);

            double limitPrice = GetLimitPrice(action);
          ***double Bigprice = SaveBidAndOfferHandler.BigBid;*****После добавления данного выражения выдает ошибку**
            Signal signal = new Signal(this.strategy, BrokerDateTime.Make(DateTime.Now), action, OrderType.Limit, limitPrice, 0, limitPrice);

            this.logger.Log(
                String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff}, {1}, сгенерирован сигнал {2}", 
                BrokerDateTime.Make(DateTime.Now), 
                this.GetType().Name, 
                signal.ToString()));

            this.signalQueue.Enqueue(signal);
        }

        private Order GetLastFilledOrder()
        {
            try
            {
                return this.tradingData.GetFilledCloseOrders(this.strategy).Last();
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private TradeAction GetAction(Order order)
        {
            if (order == null)
                return TradeAction.Buy;

            if (order.OrderType == OrderType.Stop)
                return order.TradeAction;

            return order.InverseAction();
        }

        private double GetLimitPrice(TradeAction action)
        {
            if (action == TradeAction.Buy)
                return this.orderBook.GetBidPrice(this.strategy.Symbol, 0);

            return this.orderBook.GetOfferPrice(this.strategy.Symbol, 0);
        }

        private bool StrategyPositionExists()
        {
            if (this.tradingData.GetAmount(this.strategy) != 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        private bool UnfilledOrdersExists()
        {
            if (this.tradingData.GetUnfilled(this.strategy, OrderType.Limit).Count() != 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Основной класс программы

```js
namespace scalp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static MarketDataProvider marketDataProvider = new MarketDataProvider();
        private static RawTradingDataProvider rawTradingDataProvider = new RawTradingDataProvider();
        private static SymbolsDataProvider symbolsDataProvider = new SymbolsDataProvider();

        private static OrderManager orderManager = new BacktestOrderManager(TradingData.Instance, DefaultLogger.Instance);
        
        private static TraderBase traderBase =
            new TraderBase(orderManager);

        private static Strategy strategy = new Strategy(1, "Sample strategy", "ST88461-RF-01", "RTS-12.16_FT", 1);

        private static SmartComAdapter adapter = new SmartComAdapter();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            
            string symbol = "RTS-12.16_FT";
            int maxDeph = 12;
            Logger logger = new TextFileLogger(symbol, 2000048);
           SaveBidAndOfferHandler saveBidAndOfferHandler =
               new SaveBidAndOfferHandler(symbol, OrderBook.Instance, maxDeph, logger);

           Open open = new Open(strategy,
               OrderBook.Instance,
             SignalQueue.Instance,
              TradingData.Instance,
              DefaultLogger.Instance);

            
             DefaultSubscriber.Instance.BidsAndAsks.Add(symbol);

             
             adapter.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {

                 
                    string command = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (command == "stop")
                    {
                        adapter.Stop();
                        break;
                    }

                    if (command == "Beg")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Большой бид равен {0}",
                            (FindBegemot.BigBid)));
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
                {
                    DefaultLogger.Instance.Log(e.Message);

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Значит так:

в класс scalp я добавляю строку со ссылкой на поле "double Bigprice = SaveBidAndOfferHandler.BigBid;" и среда выдает ошибку "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект". Подскажите, как передать ссылку на на нестатическое поле в данном случае.

Comment: Это форум вопросов, а не форум фриланса.:)

Comment: А в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Вы по-человечески сформулируйте вопрос: что имеем на входе, что хотим получить на выходе, что не выходит или, что не работает так как ожидается.

Comment: @Arhad Добавил описание проблемы в вопросе.

Comment: @Bulson На входе имеем нестатическое поле BigBid из класса "SaveBidAndOfferHandler"  которое при наступлении определенных событий (фактически постоянно отслеживать) в класса "scalp", при попытке добавления строки " duoble Bigprice = SaveBidAndOfferHandler.BigBid;"  выдает ошибку.

Comment: @ВладизМосквы Прошу прощения - не закончил вопрос. Подправил

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
SaveBidAndOfferHandler a = new SaveBidAndOfferHandler(...);
double Bigprice = a.BigBid;
```